# Cannot move the text box on Android Layout page

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I am trying to design the layout of my Android project, but I must have done something wrong. Now when I try to drag the text boxes around, they just would not move on the screen. I am guessing it is one of the format setting, but not sure which one it is.

[image]

This is the XML file of how it looks:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.oldimagerevieal.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you flip to the .xml and post it for us?

Comment: Posted. Just added two tags but could not drag them at all. :-(

Answer (score 0):

FrameLayouts use gravity to position items on a screen using the

```
android:layout_gravity="left|top" //whatever you want.
```

Unless you need the FrameLayout, you can change the root element to a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout (don't forget to specify orientation), and you should be able to drag things around like normal.

I would high recommend getting familiar with building views in XML. It will significantly help you.

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Autoconnection to parent" by clicking on the magnet button in the design tools section.